# Currency Exchange Program

Tags: java

Attached is my finalized code for a Lab project. I have everything done but for some reason my code sits idle? I think it may be an issue between the "bank1" and "bank2" objects and the Bank class?

I apologize that the code is so long, as I don not know where the issue is. Help please :(

**Currency Exchange Class (main)**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class CurrencyExchange {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        //Create 2 bank objects, one for each file "bank1.txt" & "bank2.txt"
        Bank bank1 = new Bank("bank1.txt");
        Bank bank2 = new Bank("bank2.txt");
        int userCont = 0;

        do {
            boolean buy = false;
            double amount;
            int banksSupported = 0;
            String currencyCode;
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            String userAnswer;

        //Ask user to buy or sell - use continue to repeat loop if invalid
        System.out.println("Do you want to buy or sell?");
            userAnswer = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (!userAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("buy") && (!userAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("sell")) ) {
                System.out.println("Invalid response. Please enter buy or sell. ");
                continue;
            }
            if (userAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("buy")) {
                buy = true;
            }

        //Ask user for foreign currency - use continue to repeat loop if invalid
        System.out.println("Which currency would you like to use?");
            currencyCode = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();

        //Check and Print how many banks support the users currency - use continue to repeat loop if none
            if(bank1.supportCurrency(currencyCode))
                ++banksSupported;
            if(bank2.supportCurrency(currencyCode))
                ++banksSupported;

            if (banksSupported == 0) {
                System.out.println("There are no banks the support " + currencyCode + ". Please enter a different currency.");
                continue;
            }
            else if (banksSupported == 1) {
                System.out.println("One bank supports " + currencyCode + ".");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Two banks support " + currencyCode + ".");
            }

        //Prompt the user for the amount of foreign currency and get the user input
        System.out.println(" What amount of " + currencyCode + "?");
            amount = keyboard.nextDouble();

        //Use the quoteBuy or quoteSell methods of the Bank objects to get a Quote from every bank supporting the foreign currency.

        //Print the quote(s) from the bank(s), using the toString method of the Quote object(s).
        if(buy) {
            if (bank1.supportCurrency(currencyCode)) {
                System.out.println(bank1.quoteBuy(amount, currencyCode));
            }
            if (bank2.supportCurrency(currencyCode)) {
                System.out.println(bank2.quoteBuy(amount, currencyCode));
            }
        }
        else {
            if (bank1.supportCurrency(currencyCode)) {
                System.out.println(bank1.quoteBuy(amount, currencyCode));
            }
            if (bank2.supportCurrency(currencyCode)) {
                System.out.println(bank2.quoteBuy(amount, currencyCode));
            }
        }

        //Use the console to prompt the user for another transaction.
            userCont = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to preform another transaction?", "Contniue", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    } while(userCont == 0); // while ( the user wants to continue performing transactions )



    }
}
```

**Bank Class**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Bank {

    // Five private data fields: The name of the bank, The commission rate, Three fields for the three currencies exchanged by the bank.
    // Each of these should have type Currency.
    private String bankName;
    private double commissionRate;
    private Currency currencyCode1;
    private Currency currencyCode2;
    private Currency currencyCode3;

    public Bank(String fileA) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File bankFile = new File(fileA);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        this.bankName = keyboard.nextLine();
        this.commissionRate = Double.parseDouble((keyboard.nextLine()));
        this.currencyCode1 = new Currency(keyboard.next(), Double.parseDouble(keyboard.next()));
        this.currencyCode2 = new Currency(keyboard.next(), Double.parseDouble(keyboard.next()));
        this.currencyCode3 = new Currency(keyboard.next(), Double.parseDouble(keyboard.next()));

        keyboard.close();
    }

    public boolean supportCurrency(String currencyCode) {
        return currencyCode.equalsIgnoreCase(currencyCode1.getCurrencyCode())
                || currencyCode.equalsIgnoreCase(currencyCode2.getCurrencyCode())
                || currencyCode.equalsIgnoreCase(currencyCode3.getCurrencyCode());
    }

    // Working on getRate method.
    public double getRate(String currencyCode) {
        double bankExchangeRate = -1.0;
                if (currencyCode.equalsIgnoreCase(currencyCode1.getCurrencyCode())) {
                    bankExchangeRate = currencyCode1.getExchangeRate();
                }
                else if (currencyCode.equalsIgnoreCase(currencyCode2.getCurrencyCode())) {
                    bankExchangeRate = currencyCode2.getExchangeRate();
                }
                else if (currencyCode.equalsIgnoreCase(currencyCode3.getCurrencyCode())) {
                    bankExchangeRate = currencyCode3.getExchangeRate();
        }

        return bankExchangeRate; //return -1.0
    }

    public Quote quoteBuy(double amt, String currencyCode) {
        double rate = getRate(currencyCode);
        Quote quote;

        if(rate == -1.0) {
            quote = null;
        }
        else {
            double userOwes = amt / (rate * (1 - commissionRate)); // This calculates the commission amount based on the dollar amount.
            double commission = userOwes * commissionRate;
            quote = new Quote(bankName, "USD", userOwes, currencyCode, amt, commissionRate, commission);
        }

        return quote;
    }

    public Quote quoteSell(double amt, String currencyCode) {
        double rate = getRate(currencyCode);
        Quote quote;

        if(rate == -1.0) {
            quote = null;
        }
        else {
            double base = amt / rate; // This calculates the dollar value of the foreign currency.
            double commission = commissionRate * base; // This calculates the commission amount based on the dollar amount.
            double amtConverted = base - commission; // The bank takes a cut.
            quote = new Quote(bankName, currencyCode, amt, "USD", amtConverted, commissionRate, commission);
        }

        return quote;
    }
}
```

**Currency Class**

```
public class Currency {

    // Two private data fields, one to hold the currency code and one to hold the exchange rate.
    // Note that the exchange rate for the same currency could be different for different banks
    private final String currencyCode;
    private final double exchangeRate;

    // A constructor that takes two arguments: the currency code and exchange rate.
    // The constructor should assign the private members from the values of the arguments.
    public Currency(String currencyCode, double currencyExchangeRate) {
        this.currencyCode = currencyCode;
        this.exchangeRate = currencyExchangeRate;

    }

    // An accessor method (getter) for each data field.
    public String getCurrencyCode() {
        return currencyCode;
    }

    public double getExchangeRate() {
        return exchangeRate;
    }
}
```

**Quote Class**

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Quote {

        private String bankName;
        private String codeToBank;
        private double amtToBank;
        private String codeFromBank;
        private double amtFromBank;
        private double commissionRate;
        private double commissionAmt$;
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat;

        public Quote(String bankName, String currencyCode, double amt, String usd, double amtConverted, double commissionRate, double commission) {
            this.bankName = bankName;
            this.codeToBank = currencyCode;
            this.amtToBank = amt;
            this.codeFromBank = usd;
            this.amtFromBank = amtConverted;
            this.commissionRate = commissionRate;
            this.commissionRate = commission;
            this.decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        }

        public String toString() {
            return (this.bankName + " is willing to offer you " + decimalFormat.format(this.amtFromBank)
                    + " " + this.codeFromBank + " for "
                    + decimalFormat.format(this.amtToBank) + " "
                    + this.codeToBank + ", after collecting a commission of "
                    + decimalFormat.format(this.commissionRate)
                    + " USD (" + Math.round(100 * this.commissionRate) + "%)");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that your Scanner is reading from System.in, when it should be reading from the input files "bank1.txt" or "bank2.txt".

Change this line in Bank:

> Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

to this:

> Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(bankFile);

And your code will work as intended.

Comment: Thank you, now it doesn't idle. But instead I get an instant error...

---
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
 at Bank.<init>(Bank.java:24)
 at CurrencyExchange.main(CurrencyExchange.java:12)

Comment: This would mean that your Scanner is expecting more input but has run out of input to read. This is likely an issue with the content of your bank files you are passing the Bank constructor. A quick and easy way to test this is to add a few lines of random numbers to your text file and see if the program runs.